# Handling memory and processor limitations of nodes in Blockchain

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In **Hyperledger Fabric Network**(*or someother **Blockchain** platforms*), it is using a **distributed ledger** to store *blocks of transactions*. So all the participant nodes will have to maintain a ledger to keep the same copy of the chain of blocks.

Here as time passes there will be more and more transactions, then 
*how it is managing the ***data load*** on each node?* 

Some of the participant nodes might have limitations in ***memory*** and all, so 
*how it is managing properly for its smooth working?* 

Also some of the participants like Mobile devices may not have much processing power compared to other systems.

How does **Blockchain** manage these situations effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a valid concern. The Bitcoin blockchain is many gigabytes large. Thus, if you want to do a payment on a mobile device, for example, your mobile device will need some other way to verify the number of coins in your account and others' accounts because it can't download the entire Bitcoin blockchain.

To my understanding, there are nodes that do store the entire blockchain and you can simply ask those nodes that you trust for the current number of coins in certain accounts. There is an element of trust here, but if you don't trust anyone, then you need to download the entire blockchain yourself.

Comment: Yes, similar understanding for me also. But there is an additional overhead of keep a separate node, I am thinking for an optimum solution for this. Also as per my understanding in a perfect blockchain implementation there won't be any 'Single point of failure' and it doesn't create a situation to keep trust on someone forcefully. I think depends on requirement scope and limitations we need to do some compromise on some of the blockchain feature. I don't have in depth knowledge in all the implementations, so expecting valuable advises from experts in its fine tuning.